# Apache 2.4.6 RewriteRule encoding for special chars

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redhat

I have a problem with a rewrite rule with some special in Apache 2.4.6 in RHEL 7.3. The rewrite i need to execute is the following. 
"RewriteRule ^/es/47006+PÂ°+Zorrilla+14 http://example.com" 
The browser response :

Not Found

The requested URL /es/47006+PÃ‚Â°+Zorrilla+14 was not found on this server.

Any thoughts anyone.

Thankyou

JVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends:

1. how path is really encoded by the client
2. where your rule is located: if it is in a .htaccess (or `<Directory>` block), your pattern have not to start with `^/en` but `^en`

Can you try: `RewriteRule ^/?es/47006+P\xC3\x83\xE2\x80\x9A\xC3\x82\xC2\xB0+Zorrilla+14 http://example.com [R]` (UTF-8) and/or `RewriteRule ^/?es/47006+P\xC3\x82\xC2\xB0+Zorrilla+14 http://example.com [R]` (CP1252)?

The `+` is really a `+`, not a space in actual request?